# Error Message:ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python, python-3.x

When run my program I get this error message. Im not too sure what is going on but what should happen is the program should test to see if a old student has been enrolled in a course and if so, the new student gets added to that course, else a new course is created in the university class registry.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamesball/Documents/workspace/Workspace/Week9.py", line 52, in <module>
    uni1.enrollStudent(stud1)         
  File "/Users/jamesball/Documents/workspace/Workspace/Week9.py", line 30, in enrollStudent
    self.registry.update(new_student.degree)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

The code:

```
from scipy.odr.odrpack import Output
class Student:

    def __init__ (self,Name,Degree,ID):
        self.courses = []
        self.name = Name
        self.degree = Degree
        self.id = ID

    def takecourse (self,course_Name):
        self.courses.append(course_Name)

    def studentOverview (self):
        print self.name
        print self.id
        print self.degree
        print "Courses:"
        for course in self.courses:
            print course


class University:

    def __init__ (self,Name,City):
        self.registry = {}
        self.name = Name
        self.city = City

    def enrollStudent(self,new_student):
        if not (new_student.degree in self.registry):
            self.registry.update(new_student.degree)
        self.registry(new_student.Degree).append[new_student.id]

    def allstudents(self):
        output = ''
        for key in self.Registry.keys():
            output += (str(key))+ ':\n'
            for output in self.registry[keys]:
                output+='      '+output+'\n'
                output+='\n'
            return output



stud1 = Student('John Doe', 'Computing Science', 5010)
stud2 = Student('Emily Dunne', 'Computing Science', 5011)
stud3 = Student('Marry Atkinson', 'Biology', 5010)
Student.takecourse(stud1,('Computer Programming Principles','WAD'))
Student.takecourse(stud2,('Robotics','HCI'))
Student.takecourse(stud3,('Biology Foundations','Micro Biology'))
Student.studentOverview(stud1)
Student.studentOverview(stud2)
Student.studentOverview(stud3)
uni1 = University('University of Aberdeen','Aberdeen')
uni1.enrollStudent(stud1)         
uni1.enrollStudent(stud2)
uni1.enrollStudent(stud3)
uni1.allstudents()
```

Comment: Is `University.registry` supposed to be a set?  `{}` is the empty dictionary.  Define an empty set with `set()`

Comment: Or if you are trying to set the value for key `new_student.degree` to `[]` do `self.registry[new_student.degree] = []`

Comment: If i change it to set() then i cant call it.

Comment: See my second comment.  Also note the square brackets to access the value of a key in a dictionary.

Comment: if i do that i get the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jamesball/Documents/workspace/Workspace/Week9.py", line 51, in <module>
    uni1.enrollStudent(stud1)         
  File "/Users/jamesball/Documents/workspace/Workspace/Week9.py", line 30, in enrollStudent
    self.registry(new_student.degree).append[new_student.id]
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable. Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you doing `registry[key]` or `registry(key)`?  The second one is incorrect, and leads to the error you're getting.  It might be from the next line in your code, where you make that mistake.

Comment: im doing registry[key]

Comment: What about on the next line?  `self.registry(new_student.Degree).append[new_student.id]` is what you copied here

Comment: This is what ist looks like     `def enrollStudent(self,new_student):
        if not (new_student.degree in self.registry):
            self.registry[new_student.degree] = []
        self.registry(new_student.degree).append[new_student.id]`

Comment: You need to change `self.registry(new_student.Degree).append[new_student.id]` to `self.registry[new_student.Degree].append(new_student.id)`

Comment: Thanks a million mate!